# Stack Trace File Path "Server Error in Application"

Tags: .net, stack-trace

Whenever someone (using my applciation) gets a "Server in '/' Application" error, they see the stack track and kindly email a screenshot, however, the line within the stack, which I am most interested in, is nearly always cropped; due to the length of the line.

The stack says something like (see how you have to scroll)

```
NameSpace.Class.Method(Type Parameter) in c:\user\myname\Desktop\DevelopmentProjects\svn_branch\project\sub_project\ProjectName\Controllers\ControllerName.cs: Line 000
```

Is there means by which I could do something to simplify the path?

-- A shorter path?

-- Something without my name in it?

Like this (see how you DON'T have to scroll)

```
NameSpace.Class.Method(Type Parameter) in ControllerName.cs: Line 000
```

[Edit] - is there a template pkage (like the 404.htm) for the "Server Error in '/' Application" where I could possible customised the page? I figure that the quick fix could be to enforce a fixed with onto the page, thereby forcing the line that I am interesting to 'word wrap'

Comment: Just change your repository location to something like `C:\projects` and recompile and redeploy.

Comment: Whilst a reasonable suggestion, I cannot escape some of the folder depth, due to the amount of projects in use and the branching with SubVersion.

Comment: You'll probably need a better exception handling design then. You could then get the exception message, the class module name (without the full path, since you don't want that) and the line number, format that properly and output it to the browser.

Comment: ^ agree with that; the error handling at the moment, is quite specific to each page/process, rather than having anything to catch-all, so means that it's the unexpected errors which throw this page. This is something that we are in the process of addressing as a longer term aim - but for the moment, the priority is to catch any error so that we can resolve the underlying issue which cause that (being that will be affecting the business directly)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your repository location to something like `C:\projects` and recompile and redeploy.

You could implement also a custom error 500 page in which you could parse and format the required info.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs